# C# SQL Bulk Export

Tags: c#, sql

I want to bulk export from a select table, all columns that match a listbox and from only rows that match listings in a text file.

Any help?  I'm sure someone has done this.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.

Read some [examples here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlBulkCopy.aspx)

I have experience with the command line version bcp.exe.  It is the fastest, most efficient way to export from your database.

Comment: does the SBC export to a text file?

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to export directly to text file from SqlBulkCopy.  If you exec bcp.exe you definatly can.

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as an accepted answer as it's not possible to export data from a database to a file using SqlBulkCopy class. bcp.exe should be used as noted in the previous comment.